# comparing 2 input radio values

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to check if the user has chosen a gender, if not, an alert/code excecution should be shown, therefore, in my HTML I'm doing:

```
<label>Anrede:</label>
<input type="radio" id="sexMale" name="gender" value="Herr">
<label for="sexMale">Herr</label>
<input type="radio" id="sexFemale" name="gender" value="Frau">
<label for="sexFemale">Frau</label>
```

And in my JS:

```
var sexM = document.getElementById("sexMale").value;
var sexF = document.getElementById("sexFemale").value;

...
```

I'm confused, because both input fields return false if none has been checked.
If one has been checked, it spits out the correct chosen field,

but when I simply want to compare them like this, nothing happens:

```
if(sexM === false && sexF === false){
    // Some Action here e.g:
    document.getElementById('').innerHTML = "Please choose a gender";
}
```

Since this is a form with 20+ input fields (form to claim products) I can NOT go with things like:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
```

I know it must be some kind of type/comparison problem. I've tried all options to compare these 2 values (e.g. === false, !== true etc) - none seems to work.

Need just a little hint, Thanks

Comment: What should be ur desire output?

Comment: One value with the chosen variable

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('input[name="gender"]:checked').length==0`.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Wv68T/2/

and this demo http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Wv68T/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to validate radio buttons. So you can try like this

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("gender");
var formValid = false;

var i = 0;
while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        formValid = true;
        console.log(radios[i].value);
    }
    i++;
}

if (!formValid) document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please choose a gender";
return formValid;
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FhgQS/392/)